# Dependency management does not work for multi-module project

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project with multiple modules and I'm trying to set it up so that module dependencies are automatically built to the correct lifecycle phase needed for building depending modules to the requested lifecycle phase.

In the example, the module `plugin` builds a Maven plugin, which is used to generate source code and is used by the module `main`. If I just try to use `mvn -am -pl main compile`, the module `plugin` is compiled but the `process-classes` lifecycle phase is not executed (which is necessary for a plugin to be usable). Compiling the module `main` then fails then with the following error:

`[ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for example:plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/ims/Dropbox/IMS/Projects/PARITy_R4/codegen-test-simple/plugin/target/classes): No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml -> [Help 1]`

Is Maven, or a plugin for it, capable of resolving the dependencies of modules in a multi-module project and build them to stage necessary by other modules? And if so, how do I need to set up the project for this to work?

These are the POMs of my project:

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>plugin</module>
        <module>main</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**plugin/pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>configurator</goalPrefix>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**main/pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>example</groupId>
                <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>codegen</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are you using `maven-reactor-plugin`? You don't need it. I assume you are using Maven 3? An other question is: Why are creating a plugin and using it within the same reactor? Why not make a separate project out of the plugin part? BTW: Can you update the head line, cause there is no relationship to dependencyManagement.

Comment: I removed the dependency on `maven-reactor-plugin`. It was a leftover from when I tried some solutions, I found, that used the reactor plugin.

Comment: @khmarbaise The reason I have it in the same project is that I want to be able to run the plugin while making changes to it. If I had it in a different project, I would have to `mvn install` it whenever I changed it, which seems error prone to me. I'm used to these kinds of setups from `make` projects, where that could be implemented by a dependency of the target that runs the code generator on the target that produces the binary of the code generator.

Comment: Sounds like testing your plugin. For such purposes there things like maven-invoker-plugin etc. to make integration tests for your plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [reference documentation for the Maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), you'll see that `compile` is before `process-classes`.

If you want this step to happen, you need to use `mvn -am -pl main process-classes` instead.

But I suggest that you always use `mvn ... install` - it also runs the tests and makes sure that the plugin which `main` uses is actually the one you think it should: Without install, the build will use an old/outdated version from the local repository (Maven will **not** magically determine "oh, there is a plugin in my reactor, I'll use that instead of the version from the local repo").

Comment: I never installed the plugin in question and the build still works with `mvn -am -pl main process-classes`. So it does seem to me that Maven will use a plugin that is defined in the same multi-module project.

Comment: Odd. If you run `mvn` with `-X`, you should be able to see the classpath with absolute paths. Can you check that it uses the path that you expect?

Comment: Which classpath are you talking about? When running `mvn -X process-classes` I can only find the classpaths used for compiling each module's sources in the output. For the module `main` it's just this: `[DEBUG] Classpath: [.../codegen-test-simple/main/target/classes]`

Comment: `-X` shows you how the different plugins are configured. I have seen that this dumps the classpath which Maven itself uses to start them. But I also can't create an example right now, so maybe I'm wrong :-/

Comment: Well, I never ran `mvn install` or `mvn deploy` for the plugin from the question's example and changes to it are reflected in the module `main`, if I run `mvn process-classes` in the project. This led me to believe that Maven does support multi-module projects where one module uses a plugin created by another module. But with such a support I would also expect it to correctly build it so that it can be used, no matter what lifecycle I request for the modules that use it.

Comment: It seems that what I wanted to do really isn't something _Maven_ was built for. Coming from a background of C programming and working with _GNU Make_, I was expecting _Maven_ to have at least some basic support for tracking dependencies between different build steps, instead of just executing them in the default order.

Comment: Maven was designed with the idea that most projects are similar and that a few people should understand and solve the common problems. The rest should just use the predefined services. The result may look/feel "wrong" but most of the time, it's because you're not aware of some important fact.